# Oneside book with centered pages

Tags: margins, books

I'm writing a document using the `book` class, with the option `oneside`.
Since the document is not meant to be printed but to be viewed online, I'd like the text to be centered in the page (i.e. with equal margins).

Is there an easy an clean way to do so?

Comment: `\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1in,heightrounded]{geometry}`.

Comment: The `oneside` option makes the page body horizontally centered in the page.

Comment: you are right. I've missed an `\hoffset` that I had given manually in the preamble, hence the problem.
The question might as well be deleted.

Comment: You can delete your own question, so that's up to you.

Answer (score 3):

Use the [`geometry`](ftp://sunsite.icm.edu.pl/pub/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/geometry/geometry.pdf) package with margin options:

```
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\geometry{left=2cm}
\geometry{right=2cm}
```